# $q.all works for the first call only

Tags: angularjs, q

Not sure why the q.all is not working the 2nd time e.g. the second time it does not wait for all the promises to be resolved.

Please have a look at the example and press the "call services" button. First time it waits until both promises are resolved but if you press the button again it immediately responds, not sure why?

http://plnkr.co/edit/JNJmX1fjsmxrxYuiNHJb?p=preview

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q, MyService1, MyService2) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.Status1 = 'Waiting';
  $scope.Status2 = 'Waiting';
  $scope.buttonValue = "Call Services";

  $scope.doServices = function() {

    $scope.Status1 = 'Waiting';
    $scope.Status2 = 'Waiting';
    $scope.buttonValue = "Working ...";
    console.log($scope.Status1)

    var promise1 = MyService1.doIt();
    var promise2 = MyService2.doIt();

   $q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(
      function() {
        $scope.Status1 = 'Done';
      },
      function() {
        $scope.Status1 = 'Failed';
      }
    ).finally(function() {
      $scope.Status2 = 'Done waiting';
      $scope.buttonValue = "Call Services";
      //promises = null;
    });

  }

  $scope.callServices = function() {
     $scope.Status1 = 'Waiting';
  $scope.Status2 = 'Waiting';
    $scope.doServices();
  }

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.Status1 = 'Waiting';
    $scope.Status2 = 'Waiting';
  }

});

app.service("MyService1", function($q, $timeout) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  this.doIt = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      console.log("Service 1 called!");
      deferred.resolve("Service 1 done!");
    }, 2000);

    return deferred.promise;
  }
});


app.service("MyService2", function($q, $timeout) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  this.doIt = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      console.log("Service 2 called!");
      deferred.resolve("Service 2 done!");
    }, 5000)

    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A promise can only be resolved once. Your service always returns the same promise. Once it's resolved, it's resolved.

You're using an anti-pattern, BTW. $timeout already returns a promise. All you should have in your service is

```
app.service("MyService1", function($timeout) {

  this.doIt = function() {
    return $timeout(function() {
      console.log("Service 1 called!");
      return "Service 1 done!";
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

Same for service 2, BTW. But since both services to exactly the same thing (except for the duration of the timeout), and don't do anything that $timeout doesn't already do, you could just use $timeout directly from your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was just playing with q.all. In reality I have a complex problem. I have multiple services calls that does server side database calls and I want to wait at least for couple of them to finish to process the rest of the code. That is why I simulated with services but I think the double usage of q and timeout which both return promises causing the problem. Your suggestion resolves the issue.

Comment: Then what is the solution??? How to re-use a resolved promise. Is there any way to re-initialize the promise???

Comment: The solution is in the response: create and return a new promise every time the service is called.